# Why am I getting this error from my show.js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my profile show view:

```
<div id='main_profile_column'>
  <div id="video_div">  
    <% @videos.each do |video| %>   
      <%= render 'videos/video', :video => video %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
         <%= paginate @videos %>
</div>
```

and I'm using a show.js.erb file to render the video partial in order to implement AJAX pagination. I have this in my show.js.erb file:

```
$("#video_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("videos/video")) %>");
```

How this code gives me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/profiles/45?page=2&_=1302255080024 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What code should I be putting in the .js.erb file?

Here's the error from the log:

```
Started GET "/profiles/45?page=2&_=1302255923695" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Apr 08 02:45:23 -0700 2011
  Processing by ProfilesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"45", "page"=>"2", "_"=>"1302255923695"}
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 45 LIMIT 1
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Profile::Listener.page.
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 57 LIMIT 1
Rendered videos/_video.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered profiles/show.js.erb (3.0ms)
Completed   in 172ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= div_for video do %>
    2: <div class="voting_div"> 
    3:   <%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "up_arrow round #{current_user && (vote = current_user.votes_for(video)) && vote.value == 1 ? "voted" : "unvoted" }" %>
    4:   <div id="vote_display" class = "round">
  app/views/videos/_video.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_videos__video_html_erb___358525845_2174681160_1885950'
  app/views/profiles/show.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_profiles_show_js_erb__196650825_2174697160_0'
```

Comment: this is the error you got from development.log or in your browser?

Comment: look in your development.log to see the real error

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `video` is null, and the code within `div_for` is trying to call the `model_name` method of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your @videos variable setup correctly in your controller/action?

Try this one:

```
$("#video_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "videos/video", :collection => @videos)) %>");
```